# Use Plone to authenticate users from mobile devices

Tags: iphone, android, plone

I'm starting to create an iPhone/Android app that will need to use Plone users (i.e. register on the website and then enjoy the app on your mobile).

**What's the best approach on doing this?** I've seen some apps using OAuth or other techniques, which ones currently supports Plone4 (4.0.3 exactly).

I have the users on a LDAP server (OpenLDAP) but even that I still have to log them on Plone to be able to send and retrieve data from there to the mobile phone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 3 options, and what you choose is dependent on what your skills are and how much time you are willing to invest:

## Basic auth

Have your user enter a username and password into the app, and just use HTTP BasicAuth headers to access the site. Plone supports Basic auth authentication out of the box.

This is not the most secure method; passwords are basically sent base64-encoded, so you may want to use HTTPS to communicate with the server. A good idea in any case for authentication anyway.

## Cookie authentication

Send a POST request with `__ac_name` and `__ac_password` items to '/login_form' on your Plone site, and capture the `Set-Cookie` header on the response, containing the `__ac` cookie. That's a tk-auth authentication token you can use on any subsequent request. This is a secure cookie, but any attacker sniffing the HTTP communication stream could re-use this, so again HTTPS is the secure way to communicate.

## OAuth

Plone does not (yet) support OAuth out of the box, but integrating with [python-oauth](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) should be trivial. This would most likely require a PluggableAuthSystem (PAS) plugin to be written.

Comment: For completeness sake if anyone is using the "Cookie authentication" method Martijn explains, you also need to add a "cookies_enabled" in the POST request alongside the __ac_name and __ac_password. I've been going like mad until I realized looking at Firebug.

Comment: oops forget the previous comment, now that I tried all combinations it's the "form.submitted=1" that makes the cookie work